# Where is the error in this logic for halting Turing machines?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the set of all Turing machines that *halt* on all inputs. Consider the following Turing machine $T$. On input $\langle S \rangle$ where $S \in \mathbb{H}$ (note that the angle brackets indicate a string encoding of $S$), $T$ does the following:

1. Simulate $S$ on $\langle S \rangle$.
2. If $S$ accepts, *reject*. If $S$ rejects, *accept*.

Because $S \in \mathbb{H}$, $S$ will always halt. Thus, $T$ will always halt, which implies $T \in \mathbb{H}$. Note that $T$ decides the language

$$\{\langle S \rangle \mid \text{$S \in \mathbb{H}$ and $S$ rejects $\langle S \rangle$}\}.$$

But $T$ accepts $\langle T \rangle$ if and only if $T$ rejects $\langle T \rangle$—this is a contradiction. Where is the error in this logic?

Answer (score 2):

It is false that $T$ decides the language
$$L = \{\langle S \rangle \mid \text{$S \in \mathbb{H}$ and $S$ rejects $\langle S \rangle$}\}.$$

In particular consider a turing machine $M$ that does not halt on all  inputs but halts and rejects on input $\langle M \rangle$. Then $T(\langle M \rangle)$ accepts but $\langle M \rangle$ is not in $L$ since $M \not\in \mathbb{H}$.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized where I went wrong. The Turing machine $T$ that I gave does not actually exist.

In particular, I required that $S \in \mathbb{H}$ for an input $\langle S \rangle$. But this implicitly tasks $T$ with verifying that $S \in \mathbb{H}$ before executing steps 1 and 2. This requires $T$ to solve the halting problem (or some variant of it).

Comment: The Turing machine $T$ you describe does exist. You are requiring $T$ to behave in a certain way when its input is from $\mathbb{H}$ (and you impose no requirement when the input is not from $\mathbb{H}$). There is no need for $T$ to verify that the input is from $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: I was being unclear. I meant that $T$ only executes steps 1 and 2 if the input is of the form $\langle S \rangle$ where $S \in \mathbb{H}$.

Comment: I see. Then I agree that your argument assumes the existence of a machine $T$ that is powerful enough to solve the halting problem and uses this fact to conclude that the halting problem is decidable, which is not very surprising ;)